# UIBarButtonItem not firing selector after it has been shown twice

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uicontrol

I use this category method on UIBarButtonItem to create custom buttons as follows:

```
+ (UIBarButtonItem*)itemWithImage:(UIImage*)image forState:(UIControlState)controlState target:(id)target action:(SEL)action{

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:image forState:controlState];

    button.frame= CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 44, 44);
    [button addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIView *v=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 44, 44) ];
    [v addSubview:button];

    return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
}
```

I then create the buttons and assign them to the navigation item in my view controller as follows:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    UIBarButtonItem * cancelButtonItem = [UIBarButtonItem itemWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cancel"] forState:UIControlStateNormal target:self action:@selector(cancel)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButtonItem;

    UIBarButtonItem * checkmarkButtonItem = [UIBarButtonItem itemWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkmark_active"] forState:UIControlStateNormal target:self action:@selector(done)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = checkmarkButtonItem;
}
```

The first time I create a view controller and push it, the button works, but when creating a brand new view controller and pushing it onto the navigation stack, it breaks.  Any ideas?  I have thoroughly debugged this and am out of ideas.

Comment: I noticed you create `UIView* v` and then never use it.  That's not the problem but you can delete those lines, they aren't necessary.

Comment: I don't understand when you have the problem. Your title says after it's shown twice. Your last paragraph says it works when " I create a view controller and push it", but not when "creating a brand new view controller and pushing it onto the navigation stack" -- those two sound like the same thing.

Comment: @progrmr good point, missed that thanks.

Comment: @rdelmar i apologize for being unclear.  I wanted to include a video, but am trying to get a good screencasting app.  They are the same thing.  I create one and push it and the button works, create another one and push it and nothing happens on touch.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the category section of your code. I suspect that the error might be stemming from something else. Some more information or code may help here... what do you mean by break etc.
Check the way you initialise the ViewController before you push it onto the stack, perhaps a simple syntax error or mistaken nib name if using outlets.

Comment: Thanks for the response and good points.  No interface builder being used here.  Its initialised in pretty standard ways.  It just seems like somehow the button is disabled or the action and target are nil'd out.